# extending regression lines with geom_line() ggplot2

Tags: r, formatting, regression, predict

I used a negative binomial glm to look at vertebrate abundance in seagrass. Because I had an interaction term, I predicted some values for fish abundance. I would like these predicted regression lines to reach the end of the plot space. Right now they are all cutting off at different times, as in the example below:

```
total<-c(1,0,5,7,9,10,23,45,78,100)
shoots_collected<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,45,67,88)
epi_bio<-c(0.0,11,0.89,1.5,9,5,.04,6,7,.9)
Year<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1)
Year<-as.factor(Year)
intertidal<-data.frame(shoots_collected,Year,epi_bio, total)

glm.neg<-glm.nb(total~Year+shoots_collected+epi_bio+shoots_collected*epi_bio, 
data=intertidal)
summary(glm.neg)
abun_shoots2015<-data.frame("shoots_collected"=rep(0:30, rep(5,31)), 
"epi_bio"=rep(c(0,1,2,3,4), 31), "Year"=rep("1", 155))

# then extracted predicted values using:

p2015<-predict(glm.neg, newdata=abun_shoots2015, se.fit=TRUE, type='response')
abun_shoots2015$fit<-p2015$fit
ggplot(intertidal, aes(x=shoots_collected, y=total)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 30))+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10))+
 geom_point(pch=1)+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==0.0000),], aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="red")+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==1),], aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="green")+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==2),], aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="blue")+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==3),], aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="yellow")+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==4),], aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="pink")
```

I was previously using the `lines()` command, but switched to `geom_lines()` so I could use `fullrange=TRUE` but it still did not work. I see that I have some missing values when I try to plot the lines, and I suspect that is why some are being cut off, but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `scale_y_continuous` etc here as they have the effect of trimming out data entirely that lies beyond the stated limits. Instead you want to limit the range of the plot to show only a portion of the data. This is done with `coord_cartesian()`, as in:

```
ggplot(intertidal, aes(x=shoots_collected, y=total)) +
 coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 30), ylim = c(0,10)) + ## KEY!
 geom_point(pch=1)+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==0.0000),], 
           aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="red")+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==1),], 
           aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="green")+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==2),], 
           aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="blue")+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==3),], 
           aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="yellow")+
 geom_line(data=abun_shoots2015[which(abun_shoots2015$epi_bio==4),], 
           aes(x=shoots_collected, y=fit), col="pink")
```

Also, I feel compelled to add that your plot could be more nicely produced by treating `epi_bio` as a factor:

```
ggplot(intertidal, aes(x=shoots_collected, y=total)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 30), ylim = c(0,10)) + ## KEY!
  geom_point(pch=1) +
  geom_line(data = abun_shoots2015, aes(y = fit, colour = as.factor(epi_bio))) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "epi_bio") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use 'coord_cartesian' inside brackets instead of its own function. I still had issues with extending my lines on my real data (it worked for the example data but not on my own for some reason). What I did was predict from 0-35 shoots even though my maximum is 30. I'll just clip the graph off early, kind of cheating I know.  Thanks, this looks much nicer! I wasn't looking forward to manually adding a legend.